# How many ways to choose $10$ balls out of an infinite number of balls of three types

Tags: combinatorics

one of my friend asked me this question
there are infinite numbers of ball of three kind i.e. ball A,B,C. I mean there are infinite number of ball of kind A and infinite number of ball of kind B an so on.the problem is that one have to select 10 balls out of these balls,in how many "ways" he can do this?
my approach for this problem was:

i can select first ball in 3 ways (A,B,C) and second ball in three ways and so on.I have 3 choices for every ball i am selecting.so 3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3 total number of ways of doing it.
but my friend argues that selecting (A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B) AND (B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A) should be counted once and similar for other sets of balls.
but as question says i have to find number of "WAYS" of doing it,so both the cases are different.  as i should focus on "how" to select not "what" to select to find the number of "ways".
please correct me if i am wrong.thanks a lot for paying attention on this problem of mine.

Comment: If order matters, then the answer is $3^{10}$ as you observed. If order doesn't matter, then the problem amounts to finding the number of elements in the set $\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{N}^3 \,|\,a+b+c=10\}.$ I don't know the answer in this case. Hope that helps. Edit. I think the answer to this latter problem is $55$.

Comment: @user18921 thanks for paying attention,i understand how you are suggesting 55.but it is the language which is bothering me.i mean order matters or not in above question?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. If order matters, that's one problem. The answer is $3^{10}$. If order doesn't matter, that's another problem, I think the answer is $55$. Since the word 'ways' does not have a technical meaning, that's the best we can do.

Comment: @user18921 i got it thank you

Comment: So, i'm interpreting that the question is asking 'How many solutions are there to: a + b + c = 10'. Maybe we can get somewhere with representing this with binary numbers (read stars and bars) where the # of 0's before the first 1 is the amount of a's, the # of 0's before the second 1 is the amount of b's, and the # of 0's after the second 1 is the amount of c's.  For example, 000000000011 means there are ten a's, 0 b's, 0 c's. 000100000001 means there are 3 a's, 7 b's, and 0 c's. There are C([10+2], 2) ways to arrange those 1's.

Comment: As Ozera pointed out, if order doesn't matter, then the answer is: $$\binom{12}{2}=\dfrac{12!}{10!2!}=\dfrac{12 \cdot 11}{2} = 6 \cdot 11 = 66$$

Comment: Order shouldn't matter since the problem is asking how many solutions are to a+b+c = 10. If we said 5+5+0 = 10 and then said 0+5+5 = 10 we would be saying the same thing. Adriano, should I move my comment to the answer portion or leave it here.

Comment: @Ozera no i think there is a something you are missing.let me explain with example,let you take 10000000000 and you have to place 2nd 1,now you have only 11 options,if you take 01000000000 for 2nd 1 you can not place it before first 1,so there are only 10 ways,similarly 11+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=55 please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You are always going to have n-1 ones (bars) and k zeros (stars). Writing 10000000000 we could put a 1 before the 1 that is already written, a one after the first zero, or after the second zero, or similarly after the last 0. Counting them by hand we have 12 spaces for our 1. The thought process behind C([10+2],2) (or similarly C([10+3-1], 10)) is we are saying "how many ways can we arrange these two dividers" or for the second solution "how many ways can we arrange a,b, and c".

Comment: yes i am getting what are you saying,we will always have 10'0'+2'1'=12 and select any 2 positions,in C([10+2],2) ways.but what are the cases i am missing in my approach,those 11 cases (66-55)?.sorry for being too pushy .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just repasting my answer from the comments section.

Interpreted as: "How many solutions are there for: a+b+c = 10".

Using the concept of 'star and bars' we write a few examples in binary numbers in which the # of 0's before the first 1 is the # of a's, # of 0's before the second 1 is the # of b's, and the # of 0's after the second 1 is the number of c's. Note, in general there are n-1 1's (bars) and k 0's (stars).

**Examples:**

000000000011 corresponds to 10 a's, 0 b's, and 0 c's.

000001000001 corresponds to 5 a's, 5 b's, and 0 c's.

**- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

The goal is to now figure how many ways we can arrange our 1's (or similarly arrange our 0's).

Note: Order does not matter. 5+5+0 = 10 is the same thing as 0+5+5 = 10

We can arrange our dividers in: $12 \choose 2$ ways

OR

We can arrange our stars in: $10+3-1 \choose 10$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: How did you arrange them then for this particular problem? And how did you conclude the answer?